# Why this css3 markup is not working in my chrome browser?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I tried to design a progress bar using css3 but when I load the html in my google chrome it is blank.

What is wrong with this mark up?  Please help me to fix it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>

        <style type="text/css">

            .progress-bar {
                background-color: #1a1a1a;
                height: 25px;
                padding: 5px;
                width: 350px;
                margin: 50px 0;         
                border-radius: 5px;
                box-shadow: 0 1px 5px #000 inset, 0 1px 0 #444;           
            }

            .progress-bar span {
                display: inline-block;
                height: 100%;
                border-radius: 3px;
                box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5) inset;
                transition: width .4s ease-in-out;    
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="progress_bar blue stripes">     <!--stripes defines the animation type for      the current progrss bar,the blue class adds a blue style for the progress bar-->
            <span style="width:40%"></span>         <!--span will help us filling the progress bar , an inline style set width will help in specifying the fill state-->
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: in CSS you using `progress-bar` but in HTML you are using `progress_bar` this is the first difference.

Comment: Your CSS selector is wrong.  The class name in the HTML is `progress_bar` but your CSS selector is `.progress-bar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your css you are using class `progress-bar` but in HTML you are using class with different name `progress_bar` see the difference between these 2 classes.

```
.progress-bar {
 background-color: #1a1a1a;
 height: 25px;
 padding: 5px;
 width: 350px;
 margin: 50px 0;         
 border-radius: 5px;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 5px #000 inset, 0 1px 0 #444;           
}

.progress-bar span {
display: inline-block;
height: 100%;
border-radius: 3px;
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5) inset;
transition: width .4s ease-in-out;    
}
```

--your HTML code is--

```
<div class="progress-bar blue stripes">    <!--stripes defines the animation type for      the current progrss bar,the blue class adds a blue style for the progress bar-->
<span style="width:40%"></span>         <!--span will help us filling the progress bar , an inline style set width will help in specifying the fill state-->
</div>
```

Here is the **[Demo](http://jsbin.com/zirolosa/1/edit)**

Comment: Thanks it helps :)
what does this box-shadow do?

Comment: `box-shadow` property gives you a shadow effect. For more information please check this link. http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/

Comment: If my post is helpful then you may accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing *progress-bar* to *progress_bar*

Answer (score 0):

## [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/gatun/1/edit?html,css,output)

You are using wrong class in css. Check out the above JSBin for working code.

```
.progress_bar {
 background-color: #1a1a1a;
 height: 25px;
 padding: 5px;
 width: 350px;
 margin: 50px 0;         
 border-radius: 5px;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 5px #000 inset, 0 1px 0 #444;           
}

.progress_bar span {
display: inline-block;
height: 100%;
border-radius: 3px;
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5) inset;
transition: width .4s ease-in-out;    
}
```